# Issue with jquery hover and click toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, click, hover

I have a map filled with regions, If you hover over a region or click it, A box(div) will appear.

When I hover over a region, The box(div) appears but doesn't dissapear after moving the mouse away from it, So if I got this right that means I need to have a toggle or something like that, but for hovering.
I spent a few hours searching around here and other places, Tried some codes, But none worked.

So I'm wondering what is the code for toggling a `.hover` and toggling for `.click`
What is it I'm doing wrong here, or am I using the wrong code entirely?

Here is the webpage I'm testing this on:
http://iseeit.no/maptest/

Here is the code I have in my jquery: (`.no19`, `.no2`, `.no1` are the regions)

```
$(".no19").hover(function() {
$("#vest-agder").css({"display":"block"});
});

$(".no2").hover(function() {
$("#aust-agder").css({"display":"block"});
});

$(".no1").hover(function() {
$("#akershus").css({"display":"block"});
});
```

I tried something like this and a bunch of other, this seems to be the correct code but I can't get it to work properly:

```
 $(".no19").hover(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#vest-agder').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Here is a snippet from the css:

```
#vest-agder {
    background: #111;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #eee;
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
```

Here is a snippet from the html:

```
<div id="vest-agder">
    <!-- agent address in the first region -->
  <p>text</p>
  </div>
```

I have also put all the coding for html, jquery and css in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cpKFf/1/
I've never used jsfiddle, so I have no idea how to set it up properly but I guess it need all the graphical components to show the map correctly. 
The code you see there is the result of this:
http://iseeit.no/maptest/

Hope I made myself clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in jquery, but shouldn't it be `$(this).toggleClass('display');`

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like:

```
$(".no1").hover(function() {
  $("#akershus").css({"display":"block"});
  ,

  function()  {  $("#akershus").css({"display":"none"});   }

 });
```

The hover takes two functions